# Display Floor plane or Indoor map on Mapkit

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, mapkit

I have a floor-plan or indoor map. I need to represent this map on UI having the basic map functionality. I actually wanted to use MapKit, but the max zoom level is not enough to view that image.
Same problem with Google map and with Mapbox.

## My first question, Is it possible to use the Mapkit to display only that/a Image/map?

I tried overlay, but zoom level is the same problem, if i set the image according to the lat-lon the overlaid image on the map is very small. Another solution was to set the image/map by any lat-long and make it bigger on the map, but this seems very weird as outside the image(indoor map), the default map view is visible.

## My second question, If Mapkit can not be used to display the single image, then what is my best shot?

I started with the UIScrollView, but it will be a long way to finish those map functionality, is there any third party lib to solve my problem.

My target is to represent the indoor map or floor-plan on a view which will provide all the basic map functionality(zoom, rotate, distance measurement, dropping a pic etc.).

Thank you.

Comment: Have u got any result for this because i too want same prototype in my project

Comment: @batMan007 unfortunately no.

Comment: bro i too facing same problem i need to track asset in indoor location and i dono how to start any tips

Comment: Well your needs has two phase, first to display the map and the second to trace assets. For the second phase you will need external device/technology, like BLE devices which will emit its position.